# Golang dependency manage in private/enterprise git server

Tags: git, go, gitlab

I'm working in a company not allow employee visit github or any down/upload file site. Now I'm investigate implement with golang but problem is because of policy above , I cannot get library from github.

I can request permission to use github for some special case, but when apply for all employee, it cannot.

We have a private gitlab server
So Is there anyway to auto clone github repo to our git server private/enterprise network

thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:maven]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact reasoning for the policy, it MAY be possible to use a proxy-based solution. At a previous employer, we set up a solution using Athens, where any internal build could access externally-hosted Go modules through the proxy.

It is also possible to do permissioning, as Athens can be configured to call out with a webhook to get a "yes/no" for any specific module.

Both of these would eliminate the need to directly accessing GitHub or similar, while still allowing space to (say) enforce license requirements.

Comment: Thank you, after check I think athens is a good solution, we will try it